# AngularJS get first element in JSON for errors regardless of the name

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using AngularJS. My system can return a number of different errors in my JSON call, at the moment I'm getting away with doing this:

```
$scope.errors = object.data.form.ERRORS
```

or

```
$scope.errors = object.data.system.ERRORS
```

But going forward '`form`' or '`system`' could be anything so is it possible to do something like this: `object.data[1].ERRORS` so I don't have to state 'form' or 'system' as something always has errors and it always the first element of the data.

My data looks like this:

```
Object {member-participant: Object}
system: Object
ERRORS: "Email address already exists."
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you simply loop through the keys?

```
$scope.errors = [];
for (var key in object.data) {
  if (object.data[key].ERRORS) {
    $scope.errors.push(object.data[key].ERRORS);
  }
}
```

If you want the "first" element, you could simply add a break statement.